Pytorch Error Runtime RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (10x2048 and 64x6)
I am trying to concat the X,Y and Rag Feature But it is Giving me erorr I have use the simple  concat but it is Giving me error I just want to concat the x,y,rag feature in the forward function, can Anyone help me to solve the Problem
How do I fix an error when concatenating x, y, and rag in the forward function using torch.cat, ensuring matching dimensions and device types?
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
class MFB(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,img_feat_size, ques_feat_size, is_first, MFB_K, MFB_O, DROPOUT_R):
        super(MFB, self).__init__()
        #self.__C = __C
        self.MFB_K = MFB_K
        self.MFB_O = MFB_O
        self.DROPOUT_R = DROPOUT_R

        self.is_first = is_first
        self.proj_i = nn.Linear(img_feat_size, MFB_K * MFB_O)
        self.proj_q = nn.Linear(ques_feat_size, MFB_K * MFB_O)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(DROPOUT_R)
        self.pool = nn.AvgPool1d(MFB_K, stride = MFB_K)

    def forward(self, img_feat, ques_feat, exp_in=1):
        batch_size = img_feat.shape[0]
        img_feat = self.proj_i(img_feat)                # (N, C, K*O)
        ques_feat = self.proj_q(ques_feat)              # (N, 1, K*O)

        exp_out = img_feat * ques_feat             # (N, C, K*O)
        exp_out = self.dropout(exp_out) if self.is_first else self.dropout(exp_out * exp_in)     # (N, C, K*O)
        z = self.pool(exp_out) * self.MFB_K         # (N, C, O)
        z = torch.sqrt(F.relu(z)) - torch.sqrt(F.relu(-z))
        z = F.normalize(z.view(batch_size, -1))         # (N, C*O)
        z = z.view(batch_size, -1, self.MFB_O)      # (N, C, O)
        return z


#MFB -> Multimodal Factorized Bilinear Pooling
#used to model complex interactions between features like image and text
#MFB_K -> Number Of factors, MFB_O -> Output size,
#Init initializes linear projection layers for image and question features , dropout layer and average pooling layer

#Forward:

#exp_in = input expansion factor (default - 1)
#Linear projection of image and question features to factorized bilinear form
#Element-wise multiplication of image and question features
#APply Dropout
#Average pooling along the factorized dimension (MFB_K) to reduce the size of the output tensor
#Element-wise operations to compute the final output (z) using square root and normalization using Relu.
#The final output represents the fused representation of image and question features.


data = data[~data['Name'].isin(outliers)]
len(sample_dataset_new)

torch.manual_seed(123)
t_p,v_p = torch.utils.data.random_split(sample_dataset_new,[450,50])

# torch.manual_seed(123)
t_p,te_p = torch.utils.data.random_split(t_p,[340,110])

t_p[1]["processed_img"].shape
t_p[1]['processed_txt'].shape
t_p[1]['processed_rag'].shape

(768,)

    class Classifier(pl.LightningModule):

    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.MFB = MFB(512,768,True,256,64,0.1)
      self.fin_y_shape = torch.nn.Linear(768,512)
      self.fin_old = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin = torch.nn.Linear(16 * 768, 64)
      self.fin_inten = torch.nn.Linear(2048,6)
      self.fin_e1 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin_e2 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin_e3 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin_e4 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin_e5 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin_e6 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin_e7 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin_e8 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      self.fin_e9 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
      # self.reduce_x = torch.nn.Linear(768, 512)
      # self.reduce_rag = torch.nn.Linear(768, 512)



      self.validation_step_outputs = []
      self.test_step_outputs = []


    def forward(self, x,y,rag):
        x_,y_,rag_ = x,y,rag
        print("x.shape", x.shape)
        print("y.shape",y.shape)
        print("rag.shape",rag.shape)

        # x = self.reduce_x(x)
        # rag = self.reduce_rag(rag)

        # print("x.shape", x.shape)
        # print("y.shape",y.shape)
        # print("rag.shape",rag.shape)
        # z = self.MFB(torch.unsqueeze(y, axis=1), torch.unsqueeze(rag, axis=1))
        # z_rag = self.MFB(torch.unsqueeze(y, axis=1),torch.unsqueeze(rag, axis=1))
        # z_con = torch.cat((z, z_rag), dim=1)


        # Concatenate x with y and then with rag


        z= torch.cat((torch.cat((x, y), dim=1), rag), dim=1)


        # Pass concatenated x with y and x with rag through your network
        z_new = torch.squeeze(z,dim=1)
        print("z_new shape",z_new)


        c_inten = self.fin_inten(z_new)
        c_e1 = self.fin_e1(z_new)
        c_e2 = self.fin_e2(z_new)
        c_e3 = self.fin_e3(z_new)
        c_e4 = self.fin_e4(z_new)
        c_e5 = self.fin_e5(z_new)
        c_e6 = self.fin_e6(z_new)
        c_e7 = self.fin_e7(z_new)
        c_e8 = self.fin_e8(z_new)
        c_e9 = self.fin_e9(z_new)
        c = self.fin_old(z_new)

        # print("z.shape",z.shape)
        # print("z_new shape",z_new.shape)
        # print("intensity error:", c_inten.shape)
        # print("output:", c.shape)
        # print("c_e1:", c_e1.shape)
        # print("c_e2:", c_e2.shape)
        # print("c_e3:", c_e3.shape)
        # print("c_e4:", c_e4.shape)
        # print("c_e5:", c_e5.shape)
        # print("c_e6:", c_e6.shape)
        # print("c_e7:", c_e7.shape)
        # print("c_e8:", c_e8.shape)
        # print("c_e9:", c_e9.shape)
        # print("logits.shape",logits.shape)


        output = torch.log_softmax(c, dim=1)
        c_inten = torch.log_softmax(c_inten, dim=1)
        c_e1 = torch.log_softmax(c_e1, dim=1)
        c_e2 = torch.log_softmax(c_e2, dim=1)
        c_e3 = torch.log_softmax(c_e3, dim=1)
        c_e4 = torch.log_softmax(c_e4, dim=1)
        c_e5 = torch.log_softmax(c_e5, dim=1)
        c_e6 = torch.log_softmax(c_e6, dim=1)
        c_e7 = torch.log_softmax(c_e7, dim=1)
        c_e8 = torch.log_softmax(c_e8, dim=1)
        c_e9 = torch.log_softmax(c_e9, dim=1)

        return output,c_inten,c_e1,c_e2,c_e3,c_e4,c_e5,c_e6,c_e7,c_e8,c_e9


    def cross_entropy_loss(self, logits, labels):
      print("logits.shape",logits.shape)
      return F.nll_loss(logits, labels)

    def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
        #lab,txt,rag,img,name,per,iro,alli,ana,inv,meta,puns,sat,hyp= train_batch
        lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9= train_batch
        #logit_offen,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,logit_inten_target= self.forward(txt,img,rag)

        lab = train_batch[lab].unsqueeze(1)
        #print(lab)
        txt = train_batch[txt]
        rag = train_batch[rag]
        img = train_batch[img]
        name= train_batch[name]
        intensity = train_batch[intensity].unsqueeze(1)
        e1 = train_batch[e1].unsqueeze(1)
        e2 = train_batch[e2].unsqueeze(1)
        e3 = train_batch[e3].unsqueeze(1)
        e4 = train_batch[e4].unsqueeze(1)
        e5 = train_batch[e5].unsqueeze(1)
        e6 = train_batch[e6].unsqueeze(1)
        e7 = train_batch[e7].unsqueeze(1)
        e8 = train_batch[e8].unsqueeze(1)
        e9 = train_batch[e9].unsqueeze(1)

        lab = F.one_hot(lab, num_classes=2)
        intensity = torch.abs(intensity)
        intensity = F.one_hot(intensity, num_classes=6)  # Assuming you have 6 classes
        e1 = F.one_hot(e1,num_classes = 2)
        e2 = F.one_hot(e2,num_classes = 2)
        e3 = F.one_hot(e3,num_classes = 2)
        e4 = F.one_hot(e4,num_classes = 2)
        e5 = F.one_hot(e5,num_classes = 2)
        e6 = F.one_hot(e6,num_classes = 2)
        e7 = F.one_hot(e7,num_classes = 2)
        e8 = F.one_hot(e8,num_classes = 2)
        e9 = F.one_hot(e9,num_classes = 2)

        lab = lab.squeeze(dim=1)
        intensity = intensity.squeeze(dim=1)
        e1 = e1.squeeze(dim=1)
        e2 = e2.squeeze(dim=1)
        e3 = e3.squeeze(dim=1)
        e4 = e4.squeeze(dim=1)
        e5 = e5.squeeze(dim=1)
        e6 = e6.squeeze(dim=1)
        e7 = e7.squeeze(dim=1)
        e8 = e8.squeeze(dim=1)
        e9 = e9.squeeze(dim=1)

        logit_offen,logit_inten_target,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i= self.forward(txt,img,rag)

        loss1 = self.cross_entropy_loss(logit_offen, lab)
        loss17 = self.cross_entropy_loss(logit_inten_target, intensity)
        loss4 = self.cross_entropy_loss(a, e1)
        loss5 = self.cross_entropy_loss(b, e2)
        loss6 = self.cross_entropy_loss(c, e3)
        loss7 = self.cross_entropy_loss(d, e4)
        loss8 = self.cross_entropy_loss(e, e5)
        loss9 = self.cross_entropy_loss(f, e6)
        loss10 = self.cross_entropy_loss(g, e7)
        loss11 = self.cross_entropy_loss(h, e8)
        loss12 = self.cross_entropy_loss(i, e9)

        loss = loss1 + loss4 + loss5 + loss6 + loss7 + loss8 +loss9 + loss10 +loss11 +loss12 + loss17

        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss


    def validation_step(self, val_batch, batch_idx):
        #lab,txt,rag,img,name,per,iro,alli,ana,inv,meta,puns,sat,hyp = val_batch
        lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9= val_batch
        lab = val_batch[lab].unsqueeze(1)
        #print(lab)
        txt = val_batch[txt]
        rag = val_batch[rag]
        img = val_batch[img]
        name = val_batch[name]
        intensity = val_batch[intensity].unsqueeze(1)
        e1 = val_batch[e1].unsqueeze(1)
        e2 = val_batch[e2].unsqueeze(1)
        e3 = val_batch[e3].unsqueeze(1)
        e4 = val_batch[e4].unsqueeze(1)
        e5 = val_batch[e5].unsqueeze(1)
        e6 = val_batch[e6].unsqueeze(1)
        e7 = val_batch[e7].unsqueeze(1)
        e8 = val_batch[e8].unsqueeze(1)
        e9 = val_batch[e9].unsqueeze(1)

        lab = F.one_hot(lab, num_classes=2)

        intensity = torch.abs(intensity)
        intensity = F.one_hot(intensity, num_classes=6)
        e1 = F.one_hot(e1,num_classes = 2)
        e2 = F.one_hot(e2,num_classes = 2)
        e3 = F.one_hot(e3,num_classes = 2)
        e4 = F.one_hot(e4,num_classes = 2)
        e5 = F.one_hot(e5,num_classes = 2)
        e6 = F.one_hot(e6,num_classes = 2)
        e7 = F.one_hot(e7,num_classes = 2)
        e8 = F.one_hot(e8,num_classes = 2)
        e9 = F.one_hot(e9,num_classes = 2)
        lab = lab.squeeze(dim=1)


        intensity = intensity.squeeze(dim = 1)
        e1 = e1.squeeze(dim=1)
        e2 = e2.squeeze(dim=1)
        e3 = e3.squeeze(dim=1)
        e4 = e4.squeeze(dim=1)
        e5 = e5.squeeze(dim=1)
        e6 = e6.squeeze(dim=1)
        e7 = e7.squeeze(dim=1)
        e8 = e8.squeeze(dim=1)
        e9 = e9.squeeze(dim=1)

        logits,inten,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = self.forward(txt,img,rag)

        logits=logits.float()

        tmp = np.argmax(logits.detach().cpu().numpy(),axis=1)
        loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, lab)
        lab = lab.detach().cpu().numpy()
        self.log('val_acc', accuracy_score(lab,tmp))
        self.log('val_roc_auc',roc_auc_score(lab,tmp))
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        tqdm_dict = {'val_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp)}
        self.validation_step_outputs.append({'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,'val_f1 offensive': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')})

        return {
                  'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,
        'val_f1 offensive': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')
        }

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
      outs = []
      outs14=[]
      for out in self.validation_step_outputs:
        outs.append(out['progress_bar']['val_acc'])
        outs14.append(out['val_f1 offensive'])
      self.log('val_acc_all_offn', sum(outs)/len(outs))
      self.log('val_f1 offensive', sum(outs14)/len(outs14))
      print(f'***val_acc_all_offn at epoch end {sum(outs)/len(outs)}****')
      print(f'***val_f1 offensive at epoch end {sum(outs14)/len(outs14)}****')
      self.validation_step_outputs.clear()

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9= batch
        lab = batch[lab].unsqueeze(1)
        #print(lab)
        txt = batch[txt]
        rag = batch[rag]
        img = batch[img]
        name = batch[name]
        intensity = batch[intensity].unsqueeze(1)
        e1 = batch[e1].unsqueeze(1)
        e2 = batch[e2].unsqueeze(1)
        e3 = batch[e3].unsqueeze(1)
        e4 = batch[e4].unsqueeze(1)
        e5 = batch[e5].unsqueeze(1)
        e6 = batch[e6].unsqueeze(1)
        e7 = batch[e7].unsqueeze(1)
        e8 = batch[e8].unsqueeze(1)
        e9 = batch[e9].unsqueeze(1)
        lab = F.one_hot(lab, num_classes=2)
        intensity = F.one_hot(intensity, num_classes=6)
        e1 = F.one_hot(e1,num_classes = 2)
        e2 = F.one_hot(e2,num_classes = 2)
        e3 = F.one_hot(e3,num_classes = 2)
        e4 = F.one_hot(e4,num_classes = 2)
        e5 = F.one_hot(e5,num_classes = 2)
        e6 = F.one_hot(e6,num_classes = 2)
        e7 = F.one_hot(e7,num_classes = 2)
        e8 = F.one_hot(e8,num_classes = 2)
        e9 = F.one_hot(e9,num_classes = 2)
        lab = lab.squeeze(dim=1)
        intensity = intensity.squeeze(dim=1)
        e1 = e1.squeeze(dim=1)
        e2 = e2.squeeze(dim=1)
        e3 = e3.squeeze(dim=1)
        e4 = e4.squeeze(dim=1)
        e5 = e5.squeeze(dim=1)
        e6 = e6.squeeze(dim=1)
        e7 = e7.squeeze(dim=1)
        e8 = e8.squeeze(dim=1)
        e9 = e9.squeeze(dim=1)

        logits,inten,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i= self.forward(txt,img,rag)

        logits = logits.float()
        tmp = np.argmax(logits.detach().cpu().numpy(force=True),axis=-1)
        loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, lab)
        lab = lab.detach().cpu().numpy()
        self.log('test_acc', accuracy_score(lab,tmp))
        self.log('test_roc_auc',roc_auc_score(lab,tmp))
        self.log('test_loss', loss)
        tqdm_dict = {'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp)}
        self.test_step_outputs.append({'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp), 'test_f1_score': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')})
        return {
                  'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,
                  'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp),
                  'test_f1_score': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')
        }
    def on_test_epoch_end(self):
        # OPTIONAL
        outs = []
        outs1,outs2,outs3,outs4,outs5,outs6,outs7,outs8,outs9,outs10,outs11,outs12,outs13,outs14 = \
        [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
        for out in self.test_step_outputs:
          outs.append(out['test_acc'])
          outs2.append(out['test_f1_score'])
        self.log('test_acc', sum(outs)/len(outs))
        self.log('test_f1_score', sum(outs2)/len(outs2))
        self.test_step_outputs.clear()

    def configure_optimizers(self):
      # optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=3e-2)
      optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

      return optimizer


  """
  Main Model:
  Initialize
  Forward Pass
  Training Step
  Validation Step
  Testing Step

  Pp
  """

  class HmDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):

    def setup(self, stage):
      self.hm_train = t_p
      self.hm_val = v_p
      # self.hm_test = test
      self.hm_test = te_p

    def train_dataloader(self):
      return DataLoader(self.hm_train, batch_size=10, drop_last=True)

    def val_dataloader(self):
      return DataLoader(self.hm_val, batch_size=10, drop_last=True)

    def test_dataloader(self):
      return DataLoader(self.hm_test, batch_size=10, drop_last=True)

  data_module = HmDataModule()
  checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
      monitor='val_acc_all_offn',
      dirpath='mrinal/',
      filename='epoch{epoch:02d}-val_f1_all_offn{val_acc_all_offn:.2f}',
      auto_insert_metric_name=False,
      save_top_k=1,
      mode="max",
  )
  all_callbacks = []
  all_callbacks.append(checkpoint_callback)
  # train
  from pytorch_lightning import seed_everything
  seed_everything(42, workers=True)
  hm_model = Classifier()
  gpus=1
  #if torch.cuda.is_available():gpus=0
  trainer = pl.Trainer(deterministic=True,max_epochs=10,precision=16,callbacks=all_callbacks)
  trainer.fit(hm_model, data_module)

INFO:lightning_fabric.utilities.seed:Seed set to 42
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/lightning_fabric/connector.py:563: `precision=16` is supported for historical reasons but its usage is discouraged. Please set your precision to 16-mixed instead!
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/accelerator_connector.py:556: You passed `Trainer(accelerator='cpu', precision='16-mixed')` but AMP with fp16 is not supported on CPU. Using `precision='bf16-mixed'` instead.
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:Using bfloat16 Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP)
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:GPU available: False, used: False
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
WARNING:pytorch_lightning.loggers.tensorboard:Missing logger folder: /content/LLaVA/lightning_logs
INFO:pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_summary:
   | Name        | Type   | Params
----------------------------------------
0  | MFB         | MFB    | 21.0 M
1  | fin_y_shape | Linear | 393 K 
2  | fin_old     | Linear | 130   
3  | fin         | Linear | 786 K 
4  | fin_inten   | Linear | 12.3 K
5  | fin_e1      | Linear | 130   
6  | fin_e2      | Linear | 130   
7  | fin_e3      | Linear | 130   
8  | fin_e4      | Linear | 130   
9  | fin_e5      | Linear | 130   
10 | fin_e6      | Linear | 130   
11 | fin_e7      | Linear | 130   
12 | fin_e8      | Linear | 130   
13 | fin_e9      | Linear | 130   
----------------------------------------
22.2 M    Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
22.2 M    Total params
88.792    Total estimated model params size (MB)
Sanity Checking DataLoader 0:   0%
 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
x.shape torch.Size([10, 768])
y.shape torch.Size([10, 512])
rag.shape torch.Size([10, 768])
z_new shape tensor([[ 0.0144, -0.1677,  0.1100,  ..., -0.1818,  0.4250, -0.2985],
        [-0.2105, -0.1002, -0.0113,  ..., -0.0639,  0.3789, -0.0553],
        [-0.1221, -0.1026, -0.3277,  ..., -0.3724,  0.1562,  0.0286],
        ...,
        [-0.0950,  0.3957,  0.3603,  ..., -0.2121,  0.6465, -0.1983],
        [ 0.0080,  0.2380, -0.0409,  ..., -0.2565,  0.0946, -0.1098],
        [ 0.1351, -0.3463,  0.3371,  ..., -0.2283,  0.4667,  0.0087]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-279b4c8e1163> in <cell line: 369>()
    367 #if torch.cuda.is_available():gpus=0
    368 trainer = pl.Trainer(deterministic=True,max_epochs=10,precision=16,callbacks=all_callbacks)
--> 369 trainer.fit(hm_model, data_module)

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (10x2048 and 64x2)



The error you received is quite straightforward:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (ixj and kxl)

In your case, ixj=10x2048 are the batch size and feature size, while 64x6=in_featuresxout_features corresponding to layer self.fin_inten. The layer expects a feature size of 64 but received 2048. You need to change the in_features parameter of this linear layer.

I am actually new to Pytorch can you let me Know in which part of code I have to do changes as the size of x,y,rag is
x.shape torch.Size([10, 768])
y.shape torch.Size([10, 512])
rag.shape torch.Size([10, 768])

I am trying for 1 week, but nothing works out. I also changed 2048 in in_feature, but it didn't work out.

Which layer did you change the in_features to 2048? You should use breakpoints to look at your network activations and shapes, step by step that way you don't run into an unexpected shape mismatch.

I change here self.fin_inten = torch.nn.Linear(2048,6) is that Right

can you let me where i have to do the changes

Still I am Getting same error

Can you print the shape of z_new before self.fin_inten is being called?

z_new shape tensor([[ 0.0144, -0.1677,  0.1100,  ..., -0.0825,  0.4508, -0.0447],
[-0.2105, -0.1002, -0.0113,  ...,  0.0505,  0.2430, -0.4437],
[-0.1221, -0.1026, -0.3277,  ..., -0.4486, -0.0149,  0.1100],
...,
[-0.0950,  0.3957,  0.3603,  ..., -0.1358,  0.3557, -0.5418],
[ 0.0080,  0.2380, -0.0409,  ..., -0.4203,  0.1773, -0.1938],
[ 0.1351, -0.3463,  0.3371,  ..., -0.2838,  0.3707, -0.2311]])
hello this is the shape of z_new

x.shape torch.Size([10, 768])
y.shape torch.Size([10, 512])
rag.shape torch.Size([10, 768])

In that case, with self.fin_inten still set to torch.nn.Linear(2048,6), can you edit your question with the full error back trace?

Still same issue

112
113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
115
116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (10x2048 and 64x2)

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 369>()
367 #if torch.cuda.is_available():gpus=0
368 trainer = pl.Trainer(deterministic=True,max_epochs=10,precision=16,callbacks=all_callbacks)
--> 369 trainer.fit(hm_model, data_module)
this is the complete error

I only want to concatenate x, y, and rag, but I don't know Where I am lacking

The same issue applies to your other linear layers. Read my answer again, understand how to interpret this error message and then you will be able to fix your problem. That is the only way you can improve!

Ok , I tried But it didn't solve Thanks for Help

Edit your question with your current code and new error message.

Ok I will update today about the error

code Modify I have done
self.fin_y_shape = torch.nn.Linear(768,512)
self.fin_old = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
self.fin = torch.nn.Linear(16 * 768, 64)
self.fin_inten = torch.nn.Linear(2048,6)
113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
115
116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (10x2048 and 64x2)

I want to concat this one
z= torch.cat((torch.cat((x, y), dim=1), rag), dim=1)

Please edit your question instead, it will be clearer.

Ok Sorry, I will Edit Now

Don't forget the full error back trace as well

Yes I have Updated the Full error

I have also add previous MFB code in it

Any Update on the code

You need to focus, I previously told you to update the shape of fin_inten which you did. Now: you are throwing z_new into fin_inten which is a nn.Linear(2048,6) and right after into fin_e1 which is a nn.Linear(64,2). Your code is not consistent, you can't just throw random tensors into functions and hope for the best!
